# How do Wappalyzer detects technology of WebPage

Tags: php, firefox-addon, backend

How do Wappalyzer detects back-end programming language of Site, but can't detect in some cases for eg: Facebook uses PHP but it can't detect and shows HTTP/2.

Comment: How would anyone here know how Wappalyzer detect things?

Comment: @WizKid By reading their website: https://www.wappalyzer.com/about

Answer (score 15):

Wappalyzer is an open source community driven platform and all of it's source code can be found on this link: https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer

This is the specific file that does the detection https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/tree/master/src/technologies

In short, it uses regex on things like the site HTML, headers, scripts, meta, etc.

**EDIT Jan 2021:**
The file containing the detection methods has changed to https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/technologies.json
Thanks @RaymondChenon for the update.

**EDIT Nov 2021:**
The file(s) containing the detection methods has changed back to a folder with many files: https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/technologies

Comment: The specific file is no longer valid, I believe it is https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/technologies.json

Comment: 404 now is it dead?

Comment: @chovy I have updated my answer.

Comment: unfortunately wappalyzer is simply too slow for my uses.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been mentioned. It uses regex to match what it already has. 
If facebook's php is not detected remember this.

- Facebook still uses PHP, but it has built a compiler for it so it can be turned into native code on its web servers, thus boosting performance.
- Facebook uses Linux, but has optimized it for its own purposes (especially in terms of network throughput).
  [Exploring the software behind facebook](https://royal.pingdom.com/the-software-behind-facebook/)

Also it's not easy to detect backend technologies if there is extensive use of API's that can be a chanllenge.

Wappalyzer also has a commandline version that I think works the same as the browser addon.

```
npm i -g wappalyzer
```

That's what I think this folks are using for there [Wappalyzer online](https://www.nmmapper.com/st/cms-detection/wappalyzer-online/)