# How to hide Python & Django technologies from Wappalyzer

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a Django site and I want to hide Python and Django technologies from the eyes of Wappalyzer and hackers.

[image]

I've been searching for this topic on the net and found nothing useful.

How can I do that in Django version 3 and python version 3.7?

How to do that in different versions of Django and python?

Any help would be appreciated.

**[Edit]:**

I've found the answer!

According to **@cizario**'s answer, I used the package django-hide (https://pypi.org/project/django-hide/).

Then in every template that has a form with `{% csrf_token %}`, I added `{% load django_hide %}` and changed the `{% csrf_token %}` to `{% h_csrf_token %}`.

> It is because of the way Wappalyzer find the technologies according to **@Reza Heydari**'s answer. If you go to any page that has a `{% csrf_token %}`, Wappalyzer finds the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` name in the input tag and find Django technology and add it to the technologies list. But with django-hide package, the input name will be randomized, something like:
>
> `< input type="hidden" name="ImNsklFHaOdsahbaz54h0AGadZW4i" value="6ARtjav4235rW81tNvZeAJATAtADTJHahaThAhYDFEThdzfergga6YaDLnNI">`

Then I went to Wappalyzer Options and clear out the cache and it works now!

> Note: Clearing the Wappalyzer is important, otherwise Wappalyzer shows
> cached technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to develop **@RezaHeydari**'s answer with new elements:

- refer to this post https://n3tc4t.com/posts/hide-django-from-wappalyzer/ to get the idea how **Wappalyzer** manages to detect `django` using `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.
- fortunately, a package already exists and you don't need to implement the logic on your own, try this package https://pypi.org/project/django-hide/, git repo : https://github.com/metemaddar/django_hide

Answer (score 2):

Wappalyzer is an opensource project based on this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218298/how-do-wappalyzer-detects-technology-of-webpage/50218863)

they use HTML and regex to find technologies of website. ([link](https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/technologies.json))

if you check the link above you can see for Django they search for input with name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" ( [link](https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/fd88b46c7789e89ad722973966151e718c083f61/src/technologies.json#L4683) )